# Does the (source) device in a tmpfs type mount mean anything?

Tags: linux, mount, block-device, fstab, tmpfs

I just went into `/etc/fstab` (Linux) and changed my line for `/tmp` (on which a specific `ext4` partition was previously mounted) to `tmpfs`. This was clearly a bit silly, but I wasn't thinking. Anyway, I rebooted, and everything is working and all, but I'm confused about the following.

When issuing `mount` I see this:

```
/dev/sda8 on /tmp type tmpfs
```

Does this mean that `/dev/sda8` is mounted as `tmpfs`? If there were any files in `/tmp`, I can't access them any more, but I can create files in there. When I reboot, mounting as `ext4` I can see that there were in fact files on the partition (that weren't visible when `tmpfs` was mounted).

Is the device file meaningless in this context?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the device file meaningless in this context?

Yes, I think so. I cannot find evidence in the Linux documentation for this, but Googling around did point me at [this](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mount_tmpfs+8+NetBSD-current) in the NetBSD documentation about `mount_tmpfs` to support my thought:

> The tmpfs parameter only exists for compatibility with the other mount commands and is ignored.

So, I guess it doesn't matter what you use as 'source device' in mount commands or `fstab` configuration if it's the `tmpfs` type.

Experiments on my Ubuntu 12.04 box also support this with some funny behaviour in other applications:

```
# mkdir tmpfs
# mount -t tmpfs Brendan tmpfs/

# cat /proc/mounts 
[...]
Brendan /home/gert/tmpfs tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0

# df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted 
[...]
Brendan                            12G     0   12G   0% /home/gert/tmpfs
```